# With the use of Apex code, how can I select all ''OpportunityProducts' objects which are belongs to particular 'Opportunity Id'

Tags: apex-code

I am way to customizing 'Sales' application that belongs to 'salesforce.com' platform. 
Is there any way to select all the 'OpportunityProducts' objects which are belongs to particular 'Opportunity Id' ?

```
[SELECT Id FROM  OpportunityProduct WHERE Opportunity =:opportunitId];
```

When I execute above code for select those 'OpportunityProduct', I got following error. If any one have some idea please update me. Thanks.

```
Save error: sObject type 'OpportunityProduct' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

Comment: I have get done this with the following Apex code.
Internally they have used identifier 'OpportunityProduct' name as a 'OpportunityLineItem'. Therefore for this query I have to use 'OpportunityLineItem' as a object name. 

List<OpportunityLineItem> opProDucts = [SELECT Id FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId =:opportunitId];

Answer (score 2):

Another way to get this done when you need the actual products, not just the line items, is as follows.  First get your opportunities:

```
List<Opportunity> opps = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Opportunity LIMIT 1000];
```

Then loop through to create a list of opportunity Ids

```
List<Id> oppIds = new List<Id>();
for(Opportunity o : opps)
{
   oppIds.add(o.Id);
}
```

Now get your actual *products* that belong to your opportunities...

```
List<OpportunityLineItem> oppProds = [SELECT Id, PricebookEntry.Product2.Name, PricebookEntry.Product2.Family 
   FROM OpportunityLineItem 
   WHERE OpportunityId IN :oppIds];
```

Hope that helps.